# Is it safe to insert nodes directly into database?

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have a bunch of nodes that I wish to duplicate and simply change the URL path. Can I safely duplicate these records directly in Drupal's database, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be better to duplicate the node from Drupal directly. There exists a module to do that: [Node Clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone).